# Objective-C: NSLog prints (null) for a var assigned to nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, null

I'm curious why a variable overtly assigned to nil, prints as (null) with NSLog:

```
NSString *myVar = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", myVar);

# RESULT: ' (null) '
```

This is of course quite confusing given all the different kinds of "nothingness" to figure out in Objective-C, and had me trying to test various IF NULL syntaxes.

Answer (score 9):

The different kinds of "nothingness"  summed up:

```
nil  //Null pointer to an Objective-C object
Nil  //Null pointer to an Objective-C class
NULL  //Null pointer
```

All of the above are defined as `((void *)0)`.

Answer (score 4):

(null) is the string representation of 'nil' for printing purposes... nothing related to `IF NULL` checks. myVar is still `nil`

Answer (score 2):

It's just the implementation of the method `NSLog IMHO`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `%@` format does, it casts `nil` to `NSNull`. `myVar` itself is still `nil`. You can still use `if (myVar)` for testing.